# How to fix my home folder

Tags: cygwin, remapping, home-folder

[They say that I should have  ~/.inputrc](https://superuser.com/a/589629/110460) However, I do not. My home is mapped to Windows user folder. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file using your favourite text editor.

(Serious answer. There is no reason for `~/.inputrc` to exist by default in each user's home directory, when the default settings, or the system-wide `/etc/inputrc`, does the job just fine. This applies to *many* dotfiles.)